# How to Handle exception while scraping data from multiple pages?

Tags: r, exception, web-scraping, rvest

I have a character vector(`x`) which consists of multiple URL. I am scraping data from each url using rvest.  It was found that one of the url in the vector is incorrect because of which `error 404` occurred, without scraping data from other pages. How to run the program, ignoring the incorrect url.

```
lapply(x ,
          function(url){
                         
                         url %>% read_html() %>% 
                         html_nodes("") %>% 
                         html_text()
                               
                             })
```

Comment: Please have a look at `try catch`

Comment: That would be `?tryCatch`.

Comment: You can check this answer for a try catch example: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/12195574/10710995](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12195574/10710995)